# In Kumo Desu (I'm a Spider, So What), what volume of the light novel is the 2nd half of the elf village battle?

Tags: so-im-a-spider-so-what

At the end of the anime I really wanted to know what happened in the rest of the elf village battle. I went to the light novels and read all the way to volume 12 and that part of the story still hasn't been told!!! Has it been told yet in any of the Japanese releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volume 14 primarily covers the Elf Village battle.